# Split chr vector into data frame based on first word?

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
con = url("https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/word-vectors-v2/cc.af.300.vec.gz", "r")
con = gzcon(con)
wv = readLines(con, n = 1000)
```

I have many chr vectors of the form:

```
> str(wv[1][[1]])
 chr "in 0.0183 0.0885 0.0084 0.0157 -0.0236 0.0419 -0.0224 0.0007 -0.0232 0.0259 -0.0037 -0.0167 -0.0254 -0.0046 -0.0209 0.0154 0.00"| __truncated__
> str(wv[2][[1]])
 chr "n 0.0102 0.2465 0.0483 -0.0223 -0.0253 -0.0609 0.0218 0.0273 -0.0075 0.0406 -0.0180 0.0033 -0.0012 0.0160 0.0171 -0.0359 0.0350"| __truncated__
> str(wv[20][[1]])
 chr "was -0.0028 -0.0193 -0.0520 0.0092 -0.0437 0.0029 0.0057 -0.0276 -0.0028 0.0057 0.0182 0.0111 0.0284 0.0033 -0.0183 0.0406 -0.0"| __truncated__
```

So, the first item is a chr in text form then after the first space there is a series of numbers.

I would like to create a data frame where the first column is the word and subsequent columns are the numbers. In this case there would be 3 rows, the first column containing "in", "n" and then "was".

Tried:

```
wv1 <- lapply(wv, function(i) {strsplit(i, " ") %>% as.data.frame()}) %>% unlist()
```

However this returned a error:

```
Error in structure(res, levels = lv, names = nm, class = "factor") : 
  'names' attribute [300701] must be the same length as the vector [1000]
```

How can I turn wv into a dataframe?

Comment: You don't have a `list` it is a `vector`  `is.vector(wv)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Just read the wv with `read.table` i.e. `read.table(text=wv, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This did return a df however not in the desired format. The names of the df appear to be numbers and the first row the desirered feature names. I tried changing to ```header = T``` and also transposing with ```t(wv)``` without success

Comment: Can you show few rows of the expected output.  Do you want to have the nrows as 1000?

Comment: If you paste the first block of code above and then go ```wv[2]``` it returns a chr vector and the first thing in the chr vector is the word 'die" followed by a bunch of numbers. Looks like they are separated by spaces. I wouldlike this to be a single variable in a df with the heading "die". Similar for ```wv[5]``, the first word there is "</s>". I would like this to be a feature in the new df.